# Is it possible to have multiple columns (two in my case) inside a block in XSL FO?

Tags: xsl-fo, apache-fop

I would like to style part of my page inside a block, or actually inside a table cell, as a list wrapped in two columns.

```
item 1    item 4
item 2    item 5
item 3    item 6
```

I was a little surprised column layout can only be defined on a page master level.

I can work around this in my code with a table, but I am curious if there is an elegant XSL FO way of doing this?

I'm using FOP.

Comment: I do not believe so using current FOP. RenderX XEP has that as an extension rx:flow-section where you can specify the column-count

Comment: AH Formatter supports `column-count` on `fo:block-container` (https://www.antennahouse.com/product/ahf63/ahf-ext.html#axf.column-count), which was part of the XSL 2.0 requirements (https://www.w3.org/TR/xslfo20-req/#N66550).  Not in listed in FOP extensions, though.

Answer (score 0):

It's not currently possible with FOP.